# Selenium only locates element when I open developer tools in chrome

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

At this stage, all the script aims to do is to locate the search bar in a digital library, send the name of the resource I am looking for, click on it and get the current url. The first bit (sending keys to search bar) works fine. But I have noticed that the second `try`/`finally` block only executes when I right click and inspect any element on the page. If I don't, I get the following error message :

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="ember767"]"}
```

**My code**:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains


PATH = "/Applications/chromedriver"
ser = Service(PATH)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ser)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(20)

driver.get("https://browzine.com/libraries/1374/subjects")
print("Enter targeted Journal name:")
targeted_journal = input()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)


try:

    button = driver.find_element(By.ID, "ember648")
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(button).click(button).perform()
    button.send_keys(targeted_journal)
    button.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

finally:
    pass

# step 2 : click targeted journal and get current url

try:
    driver.implicitly_wait(20)
    click_journal = driver.find_element(By.ID, "ember767") 
    ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(click_journal).click(click_journal).perform()
    targeted_url = driver.current_url

finally:
    pass

print(targeted_url)
driver.quit()
```

*Update - answer found*

*The ID initially collected for the targeted element was a dynamic one. It was only as such when the developer tools window was open. Therefore the script was only able to detect that particular ID when "Inspect element" was clicked as it was the only case in which the targeted element was assigned this particular ID ("ember767" in my case).
To avoid this issue, an Xpath was used to locate the element instead. See Mayank Shukla's answer below.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In some cases, element's ID or other attributes changes or attribute's value appears on mouse hover. So it's preferred to use `xpath` for locating such elements

In this scenario, I think the element's id is changing after you are hovering the mouse. Try using `xpath` and let me know if that works. Because might be after browser refresh this is happening i.e. element's id is changing.

Comment: This is low quality answer. "Try xpath and let me know" is not an answer, it is a suggestion and does not really answer question.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Please take a look at it